# Generating PDF files from a Symfony2 application using FPDF

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, fpdf

I've searched a lot on the internet how to generate PDF's files from a Symfony2 application.

I want to use FPDF library, there are some PDF files that are encoded with this library and the intention is to migrate it.

Also I can't use any HTML to PDF library because I need to create reports of [this type](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_qN_3Ojk9g5k/S-8QCPgSICI/AAAAAAAAFYM/XpXO7Dhh2VQ/s1600/Tabla+vfr-ifr.jpg)

As you can see are very complex, and because using FPDF is relatively easy to make.

Are any Bundle know for this purpose ?, or should I use FPDF class directly?

Moreover, I need PHP templating system? or should create PHP classes?

I hope you can guide me and help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle). It allows you to generate either pdf or image files from your html documents, using the webkit engine & The KnpSnappyBundle provides a simple integration for your Symfony project.

Hope it will help you.